# RefineryCMS 3 Search

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, refinerycms, refinery

According to [this post from 2012](http://www.refinerycms.com/blog/refinery-cms-3-0-0-released) search, blog and news functionality is built in RefineryCMS 3. However I see no documentation on using these. Could someone please give me a hint how to create a serarch functionality for users on the frontend?

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, that post was an April Fools' joke, sorry! I've updated the post to be more clear about this.

As of this time, Refinery 3.0.0 has not been released and search, blog, and news functionality will be optional extensions.

Comment: Refinery CMS 3.0.0 is now released.